# backgroundWorker and progressChanged not working

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

i cant get the progress bar to work! if i execute the following code the bar remains empty even if the code gets executed the ReportProgress doesnt seem to update anything..:

```
namespace GPUZ_2

{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GPUZdata test = new GPUZdata
        {
        };

        //invio l'oggetto al thread backgroundworker
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(test);
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //
        // e.Argument always contains whatever was sent to the background worker
        // in RunWorkerAsync. We can simply cast it to its original type.
        //
        GPUZdata argumentTest = e.Argument as GPUZdata;




        argumentTest.OneValue = 6;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(50);
        argumentTest.TwoValue = 3;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);


        //
        // Now, return the values we generated in this method.
        // Always use e.Result.
        //
        e.Result = argumentTest;
    }


    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

         // Receive the result from DoWork, and display it.

        GPUZdata test = e.Result as GPUZdata;
        this.Text = test.OneValue.ToString() + " " + test.TwoValue.ToString();

     }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        // Set the text.
        this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Most important thing you need to do: in the RunWorkerCompleted event *never* ignore the e.Error property.

Comment: ok thanks, i was just following a tutorial with the minimum code needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To initialize the BackgroundWorker, you must enable progress reporting and hook up your event handlers:

```
// Enable progress reporting
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

// Hook up event handlers
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
```

Comment: thanks! this solved my problem, i didnt understand that i had to hook up the event handlers in order to make it run, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see where you set the [`WorkerReportsProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workerreportsprogress.aspx) property to true - that most likely is the problem:

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(test);
```

Comment: i tried to add the line to the code but no luck, anyway i enabled the progress reporting using the visual studio GUI, isnt it the same?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. In AssemblyInfo.cs you should make this change for ComVisible.

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

Comment: Can you provide more details justifying your answer. Something like why ComVisible(true) resolve the issue etc..